# How to rewrite Cache-Control header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, total.js

Trying to rewrite Cache-Control header with

```
self.header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=86400,public');
self.view('view');
```

It doesn't work. Header still the same - Cache-Control: private.
Also tried to append headers to view function:

```
self.view('view', {}, {'Cache-Control': 'max-age=86400,public'});
```

Still not working

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, I have fixed it. Try to download latest beta version `$ npm install total.js@beta`. Thank you!